# How to validate query result in meteor helper and redirects to 404?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, meteor-collections

First of all, I am not using Meteor in itself but Angular-Meteor, so the principles are the same. What I need to do is validate in `helper` function when a resource is valid or not and make a decision based on its result.

I thought `find` and `findOne` collection's functions are synchronous in client side, but it seems they are not or I am doing the things in a wrong way.

I have the following code:

```
this.helpers({
      post() {
        let _post = Posts.findOne({
          _id: this.postId
        });

        if( typeof _post == 'undefined' )
          return this.$state.go('404');

        return _post;
      }
    });
```

`this.postId` comes from the Url params. When I am navigating through the app, all work. But when I refresh the page, `this.postId` is defined but `Posts.find()` returns `undefined` and, obviously, it goes to 404 page.

¿How can I make a work-around for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you refresh the page, your view is rendered before data is sent to client. To workaround this, you need to make sure that the data is ready before checking for it existence. In other words, it means to check if your subscription is ready, use this code as a demonstration:

```
const handle = Meteor.subscribe('data');

if (handle.ready()) {
  const post = Posts.findOne(/**/);

  if (typeof post === 'undefined') {
    console.log('post does not exist');
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. Wrapping the helper code into a handle.ready() we can all always make sure data is ready. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Khang is correct about the view being rendered before the data is ready.

Another way to do this is to use a reactive variable using `this.getReactively()`

This is how your helper will look:

```
this.helpers({
  post() {
    let _post = Posts.findOne({
      _id: this.getReactively('postId')
    });

    if( typeof _post == 'undefined' )
      return this.$state.go('404');

    return _post;
  }
});
```

The helper will run first time and return nothing (ie before the data is ready), so your code should handle this as a normal case (don't do the `$state.go('404')`)

Just remember to declare `this.postId` in your constructor, otherwise the `getReactively()` won't work.

Comment: The problem is not the this.postId because it's always defined. This.postId comes from URL state params.

Comment: That's good if it's always defined. using getReactively forces Meteor to place a watch on `this.postId` - meaning that the helper will run automatically when it changes. Otherwise you need to do it yourself when the user selected a new post